# How to store a graph in sqlite and vb.net or c#

Tags: c#, graph, vb.net-2010

I have a 2D graph generated with data from a experiment, I want to store all graphs and dat for several experiments

I was thinking about using  a table like

```
id  | value                                                             | n  
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1   | {"(0,0)","(125,100)","(200,200)","(297,300)","(4,400)","(5,500)"} |    6
```

even

```
id | x   | y
------------
1    0     0
1   125  100
1   200  200
1   297  300
1   4    400
1   5    500
```

but I do not think that is a good aproach, What woul be the best way?

Comment: I think this question should be on CodeReview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest this structure:

ExpirementsTable

```
id | Title            | Descirption        | .... more info
------------------------------------------------------------------
10   Experiment title   some description
20   Experiment title   some description
30   Experiment title   some description
```

NodesTable

```
id| Name  | Description   | ExperimentID ....
------------------------------------------
1   text    more text...        10
2   text    more text...        10
3   text    more text...        10
```

TableEdges

```
id| SourceNode| TargetNode
----------------------------
1       1            2
2       1            3
3       3            2
4       3            1
```

if you need to store pixel based position for each node then add (x,y) to the Nodes Table...